# Get value in string from variable containing data from table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Get value in string "r" from variable "sel" containing data from table "tbl_final_aut"

I am using linq to sql and from that i am selecting data from datatable like...

**.cs code**

```
var sel = db.selectdoc(Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"])).ToList();//store procedure

if (sel.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (var it in sel)
    {
        //how to get value of "type column" row wise in string r
        string r="";//what to write over here to get value of type
    }
}
```

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.selectdoc
    @art_aut_id int
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM tbl_final_aut 
    WHERE art_aut_id = @art_aut_id

    RETURN
```

`tbl_final_aut` seems as

[image]

Now in foreach loop I want data of `type` column in `string r` row wise

Comment: What is your `selectdoc` method declared to return?

Comment: it return the data which will be present in `type column` present in tbl_final_aut

Comment: No, I mean what's it *declared* to return? What is the method signature?

Comment: it will return `data of a table` which i had not shown over here and a `type column` will contain data in `int datatype`

Comment: You're still not answering my question. What is the method signature? Don't describe it - tell us what it looks like in code. Go to the declaration of the method, copy it, and paste it in here...

Comment: specifically, somewhere (probably in a .designer.cs) there is a bit of code of the form `public {something here} selectdoc(int art_aut_id) {...}`. What is the "something here" ? There's a good chance it is `List<SomeType>`, in which case follow-on-question: what does `SomeType` look like? does it have a property called `type` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL will generate a type based on what it thinks the row returns, so you should be able to use (since you want it as a `string`):

```
foreach (var it in sel)
{
     string r = it.type.ToString();
     //...
}
```

If `.type` doesn't resolve, then your schema is out of date - you will need to use the update tools on the `.dbml` in the IDE.

Comment: That the thing what I needed

Comment: @MiteshJain I'm really hoping it was the "update the schema" thing, because the rest of it is page 1 of chapter 1 of linq-to-sql...

Comment: no I don't want to update, and yes this was a simple question.

Comment: @MiteshJain: Can I ask what you tried before asking the question? Because Intellisense should have given you the option as soon as you typed `it.` - I suspect it would be a good idea to read more about LINQ to SQL before going too much further.

Comment: @JonSkeet it was just struct out of mind, sorry for asking such question